# Issue calling Vue Method via Vue Computed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I believe this issue is related to JS in general as opposed to VueJS. But I have the following Vue Method that returns a Firebase Call and returns the object asked for. This is working:

```
methods: {
  getSponsor (key) {
    db.ref('businesses').child(key).on('value', snap => {
      console.log(snap.val())
      return snap.val()
    })
  }
}
```

> *[Object]*

Now, when I call this method from a computed property, it results in `undefined`:

```
computed: {
  sponsor () {
    console.log(this.getSponsor(key))
    return(this.getSponsor(key))
  }
}
```

> *Undefined*

Why is this? Is it because of how I return my method?

Comment: `getSponsor` does not return anything. It just executes some async code.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. So in order to fix it, I need to turn the code inside `getSposor` into a function and return that function? Sorry, my JS understanding is a little sub-par.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call to async action you getting out from the function context, meaning you can't return a value from the callback function that will be returned in the main function.

The solution for your problem is to set from the callback function a property in the `data` (declare it first) and then in your computed property get the value of that property.

```
 computed: {
    sponsor () {
        return(this.sponsor)
    }
 }
 methods: {
  getSponsor (key) {
    let self = this;
    db.ref('businesses').child(key).on('value', snap => {
      console.log(snap.val())
      self.sponsor =  snap.val()
    })
  }
 }
```

If you will call to the `getSonsor` inside your computed property it will runs twice, once in the initilaztion proccess and once when the `sponsor` property will change.

Because you only need to run it once I guess or on event you can do it on `beforCreate`/`mounted` etc.. depend on your needs

Comment: Awesome, I moved it to `mounted` and declared the `data` on the Vue instance and it works. Thank you!

Comment: Minor nit: the computed property at this point is superfluous. Otherwise, I like it!

Comment: @BertEvans You are right, but maybe he wants to do a transformation on the value

Comment: The `sponsor` computed will actually cause a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error because it's returning itself.